# MATLAB - codeHints taking 99.9% of runtime (R2013a)

Tags: matlab

I'm not sure what is going on. I am running my neural network simulations on my laptop, which has MATLAB R2013a on it.

The code runs fast on my desktop (R2012a though), but very very slow on the laptop. I ran it with performance and timing thing because this seems abnormal, here are the screenshots I took of the functions spending the most time doing something:

[image: The general statement about this function]

[image: I scrolled down to this line]

This is located in the codeHints.m file, so it isn't something I wrote. Is there any way I can disable this? I googled it but maybe I am not searching for the right things... I couldn't find anything. I can't get any work done because it is so slow :(

Would appreciate some advice!

**Update:** I have also attempted to run it on my desktop at work (same MATLAB version as laptop, also 8GB of RAM), and I get the same issue. I checked the resource monitor and it seems like the process is triggering a lot of memory faults (~40/sec), even though not even half of my RAM is being used.

I typed in "memory" in MATLAB and got the following information:

Maximum possible array:     11980 MB (1.256e+10 bytes) *

Memory available for all arrays:     11980 MB (1.256e+10 bytes) *

Memory used by MATLAB:       844 MB (8.849e+08 bytes)

Physical Memory (RAM):      8098 MB (8.491e+09 bytes)

So it seems like there should be sufficient room. I will try to put together a sample file.

**Update #2:** I ran my code on 2012a on the work computer with the following "memory" info:
Maximum possible array:              10872 MB (1.140e+10 bytes) *

Memory available for all arrays:     10872 MB (1.140e+10 bytes) *

Memory used by MATLAB:                 846 MB (8.874e+08 bytes)

Physical Memory (RAM):                8098 MB (8.491e+09 bytes)

The run with more iterations than above (15000 as opposed to 10000) completed much faster and there are no extraneous calls for memory allocation: 
[image: Matlab 2012a runtime]

So it seems to me that it is an issue exclusively with 2013a. For now I will use 2012a (because I need this finished), but if anyone has ideas on what to do with 2013a to stop those calls to codeHints, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What is the size of your memory (RAM) on the laptop and desktop? It seems like you have larger RAM on the desktop than on the laptop and when trying to allocate `hints.TEMP` you ran out of RAM and your software starts thrashing (chaching RAM to swap files on disk - an extremely slow operation).

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit OS or version of Matlab on your laptop?

Comment: Could you provide some test, small example, that demonstrates the problem. This way we could test it yourself and see how we can help.

Comment: @Shai, I have more RAM on my laptop (8GB) than on my desktop (4GB). Also I checked memory use and my simulation only uses about 1GB (I only ever call a function like y=net(x)), so I don't know why it would need to allocate anything else.

Comment: @horchler, Nope, it's 64-bit on both computers, the versions are just different.

Comment: @Marcin, Well, the only function in my entire code that deals with a neural network is a call to evaluate inputs (so y = net(x)), but since it is based on an already trained network, I don't know how to provide you with a working example without providing the training information.

Answer (score 1):

Though this would scream memory problems at first sight, it seems like your test have made a lack of memory improbable. In this case the only reasonable explanation that I can think off is that the computer is actually trying to do 2 different things, thus taking more time.

Some possibilities:

1. Actually not using exactly the same inputs
2. Actually not using exactly the same functions

The first point can be detected by putting some breakpoints in the codes whilst running it on 2 computers and verifying that the inputs are exactly the same. (Consider using visdiff if you have a lot of variables)

The second one could almost only be caused by having overloaded zeros. Make sure to stop at this line and see which function is being called.

---

If both these points don't solve the problem, try reducing the code as much as possible till you have only one or a few lines that create the difference. If it turns out that the difference just comes from this one line, try using the `zeros` function with the right size input on both computers and time the result with the [timeit File Exchange Submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798-timeit-benchmarking-function)

If you find that you are using the builtin function on both computers, with plenty of memory and there still is a huge performance difference, it is probably time to contact mathworks support and hear what they have to say about it.

Comment: Thanks! The inputs are exactly the same: the neural network has previously been trained, so I simply load it into the workspace and use it as I go. The function calls, variable declarations and so on are exactly the same as this is the same .m file that is being used. They both read the same .wav file in to do the operations on. 

I isolated this to being caused by the line 'y = net(x)', which evaluates the output of the neural network. I haven't gone any further. I think I will email Mathworks support and see what they say.